# What is the default DataSource implementation in auto-detect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`Spring-boot` documentation only mentions that it will auto-detect from the classpath which connection pool to use, but which implementation is used by default ? Currently, in my project I have `Commons DBCP` so I assume it will be `BasicDataSource` ?

From spring-boot documentation:

```
spring.datasource.type= # Fully qualified name of the connection pool implementation to use. By default,
 it is auto-detected from the classpath.
```

Comment: There is no default as it depends on which implementation is detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder` is responsible for autodetecting DataSource implementation. Its javadoc states:

> Convenience class for building a DataSource with common
>   implementations and properties. If Tomcat, HikariCP or Commons DBCP
>   are on the classpath one of them will be selected (in that order with
>   Tomcat first)

And the list of autodetected implementations

```
private static final String[] DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_NAMES = new String[] {
    "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource",
    "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource",
    "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource",
    "org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" };
```

So if your project has `Commons DBCP` in classpath and it doesn't contain Tomcat and HikariCP implemenations then `BasicDataSource` will be used.

Comment: That's not strictly accurate. `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` will only be used if neither `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` nor `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` is on the classpath as well

Comment: @AndyWilkinson You are right. I've just updated answer. Thank you for correction